# Quicksort-ing random numbers

Tags: c, pointers, quicksort

I want to Quicksort a randomly generated array (homework). I'm given a function "randomArray" which generates the random array. However, I don't get correct results. Can anyone point out what's wrong with my code?

There might be a problem with pointers in my code. I don't understand very well why the (given) "randomArray" function takes a pointer variable.

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MIN 0
#define MAX 100000

void quicksort(double *a[], int n)
{
if (n <= 1) return;
double *p = a[n/2];
double *b[n], *c[n];
int i, j = 0, k = 0;
for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i == n/2) continue;
    if ( a[i] <= p) b[j++] = a[i];
    else            c[k++] = a[i];
}
quicksort(b,j);
quicksort(c,k);
for (i=0; i<j; i++) a[i] =b[i];
a[j] = p;
for (i= 0; i<k; i++) a[j+1+i] =c[i];
}

void
randomArray (double *array, int length)
{
int i ;  
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
  array[i] =
(double) (rand () /
       (((double) RAND_MAX + 1) / (double) (MAX - MIN + 1))) + MIN;
}
}

int main(void) {
int i;
/* das Array zum Sortieren */
double test_array[9];

randomArray(test_array,  9);
quicksort(test_array, 9);

for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    printf("%f ", test_array[i]);
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void quicksort(double *a[], int n)` should be `void quicksort(double *a, int n)`, assuming your algorithm is correct. You're passing an array which decays into a pointer. The declaration you have now is for a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate an array in the main function:

```
double test_array[9];
```

When passing an array to a function

```
randomArray(test_array,  9);
```

It decays to a pointer, that's why you also need to pass its length:

```
randomArray (double *array, int length)
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem since the array is correctly passed to the quick sort function

Comment: I don't even think this addresses the question.

Comment: @jwodder "I don't understand very well why the (given) "randomArray" function takes a pointer variable. " That's not the question?

Comment: I think Lucas meant to say this for the `quicksort` function and not the `randomArray` function.

Comment: He asks explicitly about the `randomArray` function. I assume if he understands why it's declared like that, he will also understand how to declare the quicksort function.

Comment: @Balerion_the_black: When passing an array to function it will become a pointer to its first element. Pointers and arrays are closely related, but they are not the same.

Comment: @GiuseppePes: No, the array is not correctly passed to the quicksort function. In quicksort: a is declared as array of pointer to double. In randomArray: array is declared as a pointer to double. It's not the same and it should invoke a warning.

Comment: I see! You are right :D The problem is the definition of the quick sort function. it should be `void quicksort(double a[], int n)`

Comment: @GiuseppePes: or `quicksort(double *a, int n)`, which is the same.

Comment: @Lucas so why couldn't I write randomArray(double Array, int length) exactly?

Comment: Ah OK it's not actually and array...I see

Comment: @Balerion_the_black: if you write `randomArray(double Array, int length)` the function expects a value of type `double` and not an array of doubles (`Array` is just the name of the variable, you could also call this `abc` or something). Arrays are a bit special when passed to a function, "normal" types like `int`, `char` or `double` get passed just as expected, but an array becomes a pointer to the first value.

Comment: @Lucas I have another question. In the randomArray function, if "array" is just a pointer, how is it possible that it's treated like an array and values are substituted for "array[i]" ?

Comment: @Balerion_the_black: The expression `array[i]` gets translated to `*(array+i)`. Regardless of the type of `array`. So this becomes pointer arithmetic. Now, you may ask if there is even a difference between a pointer and an array. You can verify that they are indeed different by e.g. testing the size of the variable. Add `printf("%lu\n", sizeof(array));` In the `main` function and in the `randomArray` function and you will see that they have different size.